# C# handling two USB input data streams

Tags: c#, usb, polling, winusb

I'm trying write a console application that could display and log two data streams incoming from two USB devices using WinUSB drivers.

Each data stream is made of 30 character long text messages that are sent at random intervals between 1ms and 200ms.

What would be the best general approach to the problem?

I have tried following:

1. Polling each device in turns in single main thread - there were many lost messages.
2. Using a global queue, polling each device in separate thread, stuffing messages into the queue. Then dequeueing and processing in main thread. Queueing and Dequeueing with apropriate lock. After a few seconds of proper work all messages from one device stop showing up.

Here's the Listener thread i use for every device:

```
static void Listener()
    {
        int currentDevice = 0;
        byte[] incomingDataBuffer = new byte[30];
        bool IsDataReceived = false;
        while (true)
        {
            IsDataReceived = exxDevice.ReadBulk(currentDevice, ref incomingDataBuffer);
            if (IsDataReceived == true)
            {
                AddToQueue(incomingDataBuffer);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(0);
        }
    }
```

And here is the main thread loop:

```
while (true)
        {
            do
            {
                usbEntry = GetFromQueue();
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(usbEntry) == false)
                {
                    Console.Write(usbEntry);
                    LogEntry(usbEntry);
                }
            } while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(usbEntry) == false);
            Thread.Sleep(0);
        }
```